# accept facebook cookies on firefox robot framework

Tags: python, facebook, cookies, robotframework

from my page i can login with socials like facebook and google.
When i click on "login with facebook" , on the facebook page i get the "manage cookies".
How can click on "accept all" and store it for the next runs?
i'm using firefox.
I tried with this :

```
Click Login With Facebook
Switch browser  1 ##  browser 0 is my homepage
Click Element   //*[@id="u_0_8_yL"]  ## xpath "accept all" button
```

OR
${options}  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver.firefox.options'].Options()    sys
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --disable-notifications
${driver}  Create Webdriver  Firefox  options=${options}
go to  https://www.facebook.com/login.php?
Click Element   //*[@id="u_0_8_yL"]

I get always the error FAIL : Element with locator '//*[@id="u_0_8_yL"]' not found.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook ids are probably not static and are generated at random every time you open their page. Try to click on element based on class or text:

```
Click Element   //*[text()="accept all"]
```